# This question is not sufficiently mathematics-related

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/algorithm-for-computing-3x3-medium-filter-for-hardware-implementation

See my comment for why it should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I have closed it as Off-topic as the question is clearly an engineering problem (due to the “one clock cycle in hardware implementation” description), not a mathematical problem.